# Informatica: Representing An Empty Column in Source Qualifier

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to use a sql override query in source qualifier. The override query has an empty port (column) that is supposed to be populated in the database using a store procedure. How do I represent ( create ) the empty port(column) in the source qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

Just create ports that reflect columns returned by the SQL override. Empty column may still have a name.